# Debug Docker with Rider: Exited with code 244

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jetbrains-ide, rider

Sorry if this question was already asked but I couldn't find any instance of **"Exited with code 244"**.

I'm trying to debug my docker images, we have a few and they work completely fine when you just run, the container is built and you can access them as expected.
But if I click on the Debug icon on Rider, it builds everything and then exits with code 244, no idea what to do.

My Rider connection to Docker is completely fine (it works when I don't debug)
Tried connecting to the Docker Daemon via TCP, it connects fine but the result is the same.
Tried debugging only one out of our 12 images and the result is the same (exited with code 244)

here's the deploy log:

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose.exe" -f E:\Git\MYPROJECT\src\docker-compose.yml -f C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Rider2021.1\tmp\docker-compose.override.74.yml up
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`
Starting src_authentication.internal.dev_1 ...
Starting src_devredis_1                    ...
Starting src_transactions.internal.dev_1   ...
Starting src_userinvitations.internal.dev_1 ...
Starting src_users.internal.dev_1           ...
Starting src_devrabbit_1                    ...
Starting src_debugdata.internal.dev_1       ...
Starting src_authorization.internal.dev_1   ...
Starting src_web.bff.agent_1                ...
Starting src_globalsettings.internal.dev_1  ...
Starting src_web.bff.admin_1                ...
Starting src_web.bff.console_1              ...
Attaching to src_users.internal.dev_1, src_transactions.internal.dev_1, src_debugdata.internal.dev_1, src_authentication
.internal.dev_1, src_userinvitations.internal.dev_1, src_authorization.internal.dev_1, src_devredis_1, src_devrabbit_1,
src_web.bff.agent_1, src_globalsettings.internal.dev_1, src_web.bff.admin_1, src_web.bff.console_1
src_users.internal.dev_1 exited with code 244
src_transactions.internal.dev_1 exited with code 244
src_debugdata.internal.dev_1 exited with code 244
src_authentication.internal.dev_1 exited with code 244
src_userinvitations.internal.dev_1 exited with code 244
src_authorization.internal.dev_1 exited with code 244
src_devredis_1 exited with code 244
src_devrabbit_1 exited with code 244
src_web.bff.agent_1 exited with code 244
src_globalsettings.internal.dev_1 exited with code 244
src_web.bff.admin_1 exited with code 244
src_web.bff.console_1 exited with code 244
```

if I try to access the servers, I simply get a "unable to connect to server".

I guess that if I discover what is this code 244 it may give me the answer.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After many tests I think I finally figured the problem.

On our `docker-compose` file we have the `web.bff.console`, `web.bff.admin` and `web.bff.agent` as our "main" projects that have the others as dependencies, so I did a few things:

- On my Rider Docker configuration, I added back the "Attach to: none" (this added a `-d ...` after the `docker compose up` and removed the 244 error)
- Instead of running a docker compose with all the services, I now run with the main ones, that spawn the dependencies and everything still works as expected
- Purged all the data from Docker, cleaned the temp folder for Rider and recompiled everything again.

Although it was technically a configuration problem, the error messages could've been clearer

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. It was a real help for me!

Can anyone explain why Rider needs a detached container in order to debug remotely into the Docker container?

Comment: @hmrc87 I could only guess Rider is trying to attach something itself

Answer (score 0):

So what actually caused the issue for me was that I was naming the image and container the same in the `run configuration`. After renaming the run container to something different it worked, not really sure why, so if anybody has an idea, I'd be more than happy to hear it.

The issue only appeared during debug runs, so I guess it has something to do with the way Rider attaches itself to the container...

Update 28/07/2022: I once more ran into the problem and manually publishing the ports instead of selecting the option 'randomly publish all ports' fixed it this time...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering what's going on here, here are some things that I've discovered.

He is using Rider and when you are debugging in Rider using Docker it will build the configuration again under Rider.

using the `docker compose -d` in your normal terminal will be able to run the configuration again without being run in Rider.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in dev mode, the application was not running. So make sure your the application is up and running.